# Allowing File Download for iPhone users?

Tags: ios, iphone, download, x-sendfile

Hope this question is okay, and hopefully not too stupid. I am not an Apple user, so not really familiar with how iPhone users do stuff.

We run a digital download store, and we use xSendFile to deliver files to users when the click the download link. Straightforward stuff I thought.

We have been receiving an increasing number of support emails from iPhone users saying they cannot download files from our website.

A bit of research suggests that the only way that iPhone users can download a file is by jailbreaking their iPhone, and installing a 3rd party download app. Can that possibly be true? More confusing still, because you'd expect iPhone users to know whether they can or cannot usually download files? Puzzling stuff.

A lot of the iPhone file downloading apps I looked at were not useful for our needs anyway, because you need to enter a direct URL to the file. If you are serving files via PHP or something like xSend, then those apps won't work.

I am wondering if anyone with experience in needing to send files to users – some of whom might be using iPhones – are there any best practises for that? Or, anyone with experience with similar kinds of headaches?

Any pointers you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: do so, that iPhone users can receive by mail instead of a download link... how ever iPhone users could just download it on their computer and then sync with the iPhone

Comment: Thanks Kenny - sending a download link via email is still much the same problem - except the link is in a different place. The problem is not getting the link in front of the user. The problem is how to serve a file to an iPhone user so they can save it to their phone. If such a thing is even possible on a standard iPhone.

Comment: well you can't save files on iPhone unless you have a app to save it in... i'm thinking sending it to their emails that way they have it "saved" then if it's audio they can listen to it or if it's text they can open it in pages etc. and from there save it to their iCloud or in the app they use...
what kind of files is it they should receive ?

Comment: Ah you are talking about sending the actual files to their email. Files can be big - music videos, software. Too big for email really :( So basically, the only way to save a file onto an iPhone, is through an app that Apple has to approve? Standard iPhone / Safari / Other iphone browser does not allow file download as standard??

Comment: not the actual file but the link to it :) that way they can choose to download it and view it in a app if there is a app for it